# How do I filter out "Added a missed class for missing class telemetry" warnings when running the Jenkins test harness?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using the Jenkins test harness (starting with this example usage: https://github.com/testcookbook/jenkins_harness) and this warning is killing me

Was this fixed? I tried following the issues but it's left me more confused. I just want to NOT see it in my output: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60725?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel, https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60725, https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60725

I'm using this version of Jenkins and the harness:

```
testCompile "org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-test-harness:2.64"
testCompile "org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-war:2.235"
```

I set `testLogging.showStandardStreams true` in the build.gradle file because I want to see output of the script (I also write debug messages with print). This warning is making the test harness practically unusable because it's flooding the output. What options do I have for filtering it out?

### Edit

Setting `events 'standard_out'` doesn't show the warnings but now I'm missing a lot of stuff.

Comment: The issue you linked to seems to indicate that you run your tests on JDK 11, but on a non-Oracle version. Is that so? Maybe JENKINS-61920 is also related. That one is marked as fixed in Jenkins 2.237. Maybe an update helps, I don't know. Maybe you can deactivate Jenkins-specific logging or log Jenkins output into a file instead of on the console if it is not relevant for your tests and clutters your Spock output. You will see the build results on Jenkins, I guess. In any case this is not a Spock issue, which is why I removed the tag.

Comment: If you would log to a log server like Logstash, there you would have various filter options. For the good old console you could use some custom-made _sed_ script until the logging problem is fixed. In either case, finally it ought to be fixed at the root (the Jenkins module/plugin causing it), not somewhere else. Did you consider using Oracle JDK on the Jenkins server or is that not an option?

Comment: there is no server this is running locally per the first link. this is the test harness

Comment: What about my other suggestions concerning switching JDK version or using _sed_?