# Is there a way to ignore warnings from dependencies in the gradle build config?

Tags: gradle, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to see stdout and other logs but I want to ignore warning being generated by some dependancies

In my gradle file i include these dependancies:

```
dependencies {
    .....
    // Jenkins plugins to install
    testPlugins "org.jenkins-ci.plugins:cloudbees-folder:6.12"
    testPlugins "org.jenkins-ci.plugins:cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source:2.7.0"
    testPlugins "org.kohsuke:groovy-sandbox:1.23"
    testPlugins "org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-api:2.37"
    testPlugins "org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-multibranch:2.21"
    testPlugins "org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.6.0"
    testPlugins "com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.7.0"
    testPlugins "org.jenkins-ci.plugins:script-security:1.64"
    testPlugins "com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.3"
    .....
```

This is the entire gradle config: https://github.com/testcookbook/jenkins_harness/blob/master/build.gradle

Each one generates a massive stack trace `WARNING j.t.i.j.MissingClassTelemetry#reportException: Added a missed class for missing class telemetry.`

This makes my spock test output unreadable because my command line buffer is flooded

Is there a way to have gradle swallow warning generated by specific dependancies?

Comment: This question duplicates your own question asked yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63003371/1082681), just with a little more Gradle config and slightly different tags. Please rather update the original question with additional details than asking a duplicate question. I recommend to delete this one. BTW, this is a Jenkins question, not s Spock question.

Comment: this question is gradle specific. if its possible to use gradles features to filter out warnings generated by dependancies

Comment: Which is why I had removed the _spock_ tag at the time of my comment. Anyway, I still think it is a duplicate: same project, same problem. You could have asked about Gradle in the original question. BTW, I use Maven, not Gradle, but googled for a minute. Did you consider running Gradle with `-q|--quiet` as described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html)?